# Phonegap Tablet won't clear image when .src=''

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a button that clears an image in Phonegap App. On click it executes the following code:

```
document.getElementById('image').src='';
```

It works on my phones, but it doesn't work on tablets. I am not sure why. On all the iPads and Android tablets the image stays there, but it works when it is on Android phones and iPhones.

Edit

```
$('#image').attr('src','');
```

Comment: src='' is not a reliable way to do what you expect that it'll do... Add a transparent image instead as the src

Comment: What if you just hide your image like: document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'none';

Comment: I can't really hide it, because i would need to add another dynamic image in. So i need to remove it then add another new src, i added in another way in the Edit, if thats good? I am going to test that out right now

Comment: You can show it again once you set the new image.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! $('#image').attr('src',''); doesnt work either, i will try to hide it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both doesn't work for Tablet, as Peanut said, have to hide it(set it to None, then when you have a new src, then set it back to inline then it will work) but for Iphones and Android phones, the src='' works, just not for ipads and android pads